# QoS trough UPnP for improved VoIP quality on wireless lans

Tags: c++, voip, upnp, qos

I'm working on an application that does VoIP, Cam-streaming and file transfers at the same time. Currently it runs under Windows, OS X, Android and iPhone/iPad. As you may understand, this can create quite some network traffic, especially if several people on the same LAN does it simultaneously. As a result, VoIP quality suffers.

I figure that the best theoretical solution is to ask the local wi-fi router politely if it can prioritize the VoIP traffic. Unfortunately, most of the traffic streams, including SIP for VoIP and Video is encrypted and sent over TCP. So the router has no way to figure out what TCP/UDP streams does what.

I have looked briefly at UPnP QoS. From the specifications, it's just what I need. But I don't know if it is widely available for today's home routers. I also don't know if it actually works the way I want. To put it simple: For VoIP, I want to specify a stream by it's endpoints, and tell the wi-fi router/home network to give it minimum latency.

So my questions are really:

- Is it worth the effort to dig further into UPnP QoS?
- Is this widely adapted by modern home LAN hardware (wi-fi routers)?
- Are there better approaches to consider?

I also noted that Samsung has a patent pending for this, and I am concerned about the implications.

I have not found any really nice API's for UPnP and QoS, but I guess it's possible to cook something together with curl or boost::asio. If I do, is there any interest for a C++ Open Source library for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Encryption doesn't play a part in QoS as encryption is (usually) at the application level not the TCP/IP level.

More likely your problems are related to http://www.bufferbloat.net/

Comment: The encryption prevents the routers from identifying the RTP traffic as RTP traffic. So even if they have logic to handle VoIP media streams in a good way, it wont work in this case. Thanks for the link btw :)